# How to reset the environmental variables in AWS codebuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I m using  CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER in AWS Code build to append the build number to the artifacts that are deployed from the build. After every major version release, we need to again reset the build numbers.
For example, after v2.0.0-401 if we want to start building v3.0.0-1, not finding a way to reset the build numbers on the same code build project.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> not finding a way to reset the build numbers on the same code build project.

This is because you **can't reset it**. Its managed by AWS.

You can setup new build project to start counting from zero if you want, or use different way of tagging your builds, not based on `CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this functionality is not available out of the box, but will be definitely useful.

For now my recommendation would be to keep your CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER in the SSM Parameter Store, CodeBuild has native integration with Param Store, providing easy way to lookup value:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.env.parameter-store

Answer (score 0):

Every time I roll the version number I just track it in my buildspec instead of having to store things anywhere else.

```
- $buildPrefix = "2.0.0."
- $resetBuildNumber = 8 #this should be set to the build number prior to a buildPrefix version update
- $currentBuild = "$buildPrefix" + ($env:CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER - $resetBuildNumber)
```